# Getting trouble to fetch GeoJson properties from OpenLayers.Layer.Vector object

Tags: maps, openlayers

I've tried heard to solve the issue from previous questions raised in SE but unable to solve the issue by reading those So, posting as separate question.

I'm creating a `marker` layer using following code

```
mLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(layerName, {
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        extractAttributes: true,
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default' : Lstyle}),
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: getURL,
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        })
    });
```

My task is to calculate the average of the `marker` coordinates and set that as a center of the map, for that I want to fetch coordinates from `mLayer` object. Markers are displaying fine on map but when I'm printing `mLayer.features.length` in console it showing `0` but the size of the `features` is 10, this I'm able to see in `firebug console` by printing `vLayer`,[this](http://jsonfiddle.net/95tfb) is the my JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set map center to `markers mid point` as `Christophe Roussy` suggested in `comments` is correct to some extent, but the problem with his code is, code will execute before `layer` is finished to download to browser, So for that we have to check whether the layer is finished or not as follows

`layer.events.register('loadend', layer, function(evt){map.zoomToExtent(layer.getDataExtent() )} )`

Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers provides this feature:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getDataExtent

Then use `map.getZoomForExtent` and `map.panTo`.

Comment: before calling `map.getZoomForExtent` and `map.panTo`,how can I get coordinate values ? is both functions are necessary to call to change the map center ?

Comment: `getDataExtent` will automatically get the external bounds of your marker layer for you (because it can access the coordinates), do this `var bounds = layer.getDataExtent(); map.zoomToExtent(bounds);`

Comment: I've did,how you have suggested but map center is pointing to wrong location, might be problem with projections ?

Comment: its not problem with projection, `Var bounds = layer.getDataExtent();console.log(bounds);` showing `null` on console.

Comment: because `layer.getDataExtent()` returning `null`.

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getDataExtent
`Returns {OpenLayers.Bounds} or null if the layer has no features with geometries.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24508/discussion-between-mahesh-d-and-christophe-roussy)